# What is the best alternative to strncpy()?

Tags: c, strncpy

The function `strncpy()` doesn't always null terminate so I want to know what is the best alternative that always null terminates?
I want a function that if:

```
strlen(src) >= n /*n is the number of characters to be copied from source*/
```

there's no need to add further code like this:

```
buf[sizeof(buf)-1] = 0;
```

Comment: Look at [`strncpy_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy)

Comment: Have a look at the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/). You can use strcpy() or add the character yourself, if you know the n value. destination[n] = '\0'

Comment: @Carles Yea i know but i want to know a function that automatically appends the null character at the end of the string

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Maybe a code example will help narrow down what your trying to do.

Comment: `strncpy` inserts null bytes if the passed maximum size is larger than `strlen` of the passed string. Maybe you can use that.

Comment: @RoadRunner Does `snprintf` always null terminate?

Comment: `snprintf` always null-terminates unless the buffer size is 0

Comment: Why does it matter if you have to add null termination yourself or if the function does it for you? And even you have such irrational requirements, you can simply wrap in the code inside another function.

Comment: Note that the third argument to `strncpy` is the output buffer size, not the number of characters to be copied

Comment: Your requirements are still vague. For example please explain whether this function should handle the case of `strlen(src) < n`  (and if so, what you want to happen in that case)

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych, should the right usage of strncpy_s() be - 
strncpy(destString, sizeof(destString), srcString, (sizeof(srcString)>sizeof(destString)?(sizeof(destString)-1):(sizeof(srcString)-1)));
to handle all the possible scenarios gracefully - ie
1. when the srcString is greater than destString, then truncate the srcString to the length destString.
2. when the destString is greater than srcString.
3. when both srcString and destString are of same length.
4. when srcString is not NULL terminated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the length of the string you desire to copy is unknown, you can use [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) here. This function sends formatted output to *str*. It acts similarily to `sprintf()`, but instead does not write more bytes allocated by *str*. If the resulting string is longer than `n-1` characters, then the remaining characters are left out. It also always includes the null terminator `\0`, unless the buffer size is `0`.

This would be a alternative to `strncpy()` or `strcpy()`, if you really don't want to use it. However, manually adding a null terminator at the end of your string with `strcpy()` is always a simple, efficient approach. It is very normal in C to add a null terminator at the end of any processed string.

Here is a basic example of using `sprintf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 1024

int main(void) {
    const size_t N = SIZE;
    char str[N];
    const char *example = "Hello World";

    snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%s", example);

    printf("String = %s, Length = %zu\n", str, strlen(str));

    return 0;
}
```

Which prints out:

```
String = Hello World, Length = 11
```

This example shows that `snprintf()` copied over `"Hello World"` into `str`, and also added a `\0` terminator at the end.

**Note:** `strlen()` only works on null terminated strings, and will cause [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799336/is-strlen-on-a-string-with-unitialized-values-undefined-behavior) if the string is not null terminated. `snprintf()` also needs more error checking, which can be found on the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

As others have said, this is not an efficient approach, but it is there if you go looking.

Comment: Small example would be good. We don't want beginners doing something horrible like `snprintf(dst, DST_SIZE, src);`

Comment: snprintf is horrible inefficient. If you only wish to use it to copy strings, you are wasting resources.

Comment: @user694733 added a basic example, I'm still not sure why OP doesnt want to use `strcpy()` though.

Comment: @Lundin You are right, but the OP seemed interested, so I gave an answer. Using `strcpy()` and the example you gave is the better approach.

Comment: @Lundin snprintf has the advantage of working correctly when the source length is unknown, and the length parameter given is the output buffer size. (OP has since edited question to apparently say that that is not his use case)

Comment: @M.M OP stated earlier that he simply wants a function which automatically adds the null terminator to a string. I believe if that is the OPs requirement, then `snprintf()` is a valid option. Judging from his question, it doesn't seem efficiency is his highest priority.

Comment: @lundin Disagree this is horrible inefficient.  Optimizing compilers will see inside the format and can create very efficient code.

Comment: @chux I doubt it. And no matter execution speed, that function will take up a big chunk of program memory, for such a trivial task.

Comment: @lundin The compiler is not required to even make a function and a function call.  Code need not  take up a big chunk of program memory.  It just needs to implement the functionality.  `sprintf(dest, "%s", from);` and `strcpy(dest, from);` can emit the same code and neither call a function.

Answer (score 11):

If the behavior you want is a truncating version of `strcpy` that copies the longest initial prefix of the source string into a buffer of known size, there are multiple options for you:

- You can write a tailor made function that does the job:

  ```
  char *safe_strcpy(char *dest, size_t size, char *src) {
      if (size > 0) {
          size_t i;
          for (i = 0; i < size - 1 && src[i]; i++) {
               dest[i] = src[i];
          }
          dest[i] = '\0';
      }
      return dest;
  }
  ```

  Most BSD systems have a function `strlcpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);` that operates the same.  The order of its arguments is confusing as `n` is usually the size of the `dest` array, but comes after the `src` argument.
- You can use `strncat()`:

  ```
  char *safe_strcpy(char *dest, size_t size, char *src) {
      if (size > 0) {
          *dest = '\0';
          return strncat(dest, src, size - 1);
      }
      return dest;
  }
  ```
- You can use `snprintf()` or `sprintf()`, but it feels like using a hydraulic press to drive in a nail:

  ```
  snprintf(dest, size, "%s", src);
  ```

  Alternately:

  ```
  if (size > 0) {
      sprintf(dest, "%.*s", (int)(size - 1), src);
  }
  ```
- You can use `strlen()` and `memcpy()`, but this is only possible if you know that the source pointer points to a null terminated string.  It is also less efficient than both of the above solutions if the source string is much longer than the destination array:

  ```
  char *safe_strcpy(char *dest, size_t size, char *src) {
      if (size > 0) {
          size_t len = strlen(src);
          if (len >= size)
              len = size - 1;
          memcpy(dest, src, len);
          dest[len] = '\0';
      }
      return dest;
  }
  ```

  The inefficiency can be avoided with `strnlen()` if available on the target system:

  ```
  char *safe_strcpy(char *dest, size_t size, char *src) {
      if (size > 0) {
          size_t len = strnlen(src, size - 1);
          memcpy(dest, src, len);
          dest[len] = '\0';
      }
      return dest;
  }
  ```
- You could use `strncpy()` and force null termination.  This would be inefficient if the destination array is large because `strncpy()` also fills the rest of the destination array with null bytes if the source string is shorter.  This function's semantics are very counter-intuitive, poorly understood and error-prone. Even when used correctly, occurrences of `strncpy()` are bugs waiting to bite, as the next programmer, bolder but less savvy, might alter the code and introduce them in an attempt to *optimize* code he does not fully understand.  Play it safe: avoid this function.

Another aspect of this question is the ability for the caller to detect truncation.  The above implementations of `safe_strcpy` return the target pointer, as `strcpy` does, hence do not provide any information to the caller. `snprintf()` returns an `int` representing the number of characters that would have been copied if the target array was large enough, in this case, the return value is `strlen(src)` converted to `int`, which allows the caller to detect truncation and other errors.

Here is another function more appropriate for composing a string from different parts:

```
size_t strcpy_at(char *dest, size_t size, size_t pos, const char *src) {
    size_t len = strlen(src);
    if (pos < size) {
        size_t chunk = size - pos - 1;
        if (chunk > len)
            chunk = len;
        memcpy(dest + pos, src, chunk);
        dest[pos + chunk] = '\0';
    }
    return pos + len;
}
```

This function can be used in sequences without undefined behavior:

```
void say_hello(const char **names, size_t count) {
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    char *p = buf;
    size_t size = sizeof buf;

    for (;;) {
        size_t pos = strcpy_at(p, size, 0, "Hello");
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            pos = strcpy_at(p, size, pos, " ");
            pos = strcpy_at(p, size, pos, names[i]);
        }
        pos = strcpy_at(p, size, pos, "!");
        if (pos >= size && p == buf) {
            // allocate a larger buffer if required
            p = malloc(size = pos + 1);
            if (p != NULL)
                continue;
            p = buf;
        }
        printf("%s\n", p);
        if (p != buf)
            free(p);
        break;
    }
}
```

An equivalent approach for `snprintf` would be useful too, passing `pos` by address:

```
size_t snprintf_at(char *s, size_t n, size_t *ppos, const char *format, ...) {
    va_list arg;
    int ret;
    size_t pos = *ppos;

    if (pos < n) {
        s += pos;
        n -= pos;
    } else {
        s = NULL;
        n = 0;
    }
    va_start(arg, format);
    ret = snprintf(s, n, format, arg);
    va_end(arg);

    if (ret >= 0)
        *ppos += ret;

    return ret;
}
```

passing `pos` by address instead of by value allows for `snprintf_at` to return `snprintf`'s return value, which can be `-1` in case of encoding error.

Answer (score 9):

As an illustration of having to use an alternative to `strncpy()`, consider Git 2.19 (Q3 2018) which finds that it is too easy to misuse system API functions such as strcat(); `strncpy()`; ...  these selected functions are now forbidden in this codebase and will cause a compilation failure.

That patch does list several alternatives, which makes it relevant for this question.

See [commit e488b7a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e488b7aba743d23b830d239dcc33d9ca0745a9ad), [commit cc8fdae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc8fdaee1eeaf05d8dd55ff11f111b815f673c58), [commit 1b11b64](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b11b64b815db62f93a04242e4aed5687a448748) (24 Jul 2018), and [commit c8af66a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8af66ab8ad7cd78557f0f9f5ef6a52fd46ee6dd) (26 Jul 2018) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e28daf2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e28daf222f51f137d9038a58812f2a89f414781e), 15 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### `banned.h`: mark `strncpy()` as banned
>
> The `strncpy()` function is less horrible than `strcpy()`, but is still pretty easy to misuse because of its funny termination semantics.
>   Namely, that if it truncates it omits the NUL terminator, and you must remember to add it yourself. Even if you use it correctly, it's sometimes hard for a reader to verify this without hunting through the code.
>   If you're thinking about using it, consider instead:
>
> - `strlcpy()` if you really just need a truncated but NUL-terminated string (we provide a compat version, so it's always available)
> - `xsnprintf()` if you're sure that what you're copying should fit
> - `strbuf` or `xstrfmt()` if you need to handle arbitrary-length heap-allocated strings.
>
> Note that there is one instance of `strncpy` in `compat/regex/regcomp.c`, which is fine (it allocates a sufficiently large string before copying).
>   But this doesn't trigger the ban-list even when compiling with `NO_REGEX=1`, because:
>
> 1. we don't use git-compat-util.h when compiling it (instead we rely on the system includes from the upstream library); and
> 2. It's in an "`#ifdef DEBUG`" block
>
> Since it's doesn't trigger the `banned.h` code, we're better off leaving it to keep our divergence from upstream minimal.

---

Note: 1+ year later, with Git 2.21 (Q1 2019), the "`strncat()`" function itself is now *also* among the banned functions.

See [commit ace5707](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ace5707a803eda0f1dde3d776dc3729d3bc7759a) (02 Jan 2019) by [Eric Wong (`ele828`)](https://github.com/ele828).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 81bf66b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81bf66b760b8bbb3673e0f0cbc559671c049fc78), 18 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### `banned.h`: mark `strncat()` as banned
>
> `strncat()` has the same quadratic behavior as `strcat()` and is difficult-to-read and bug-prone.  While it hasn't yet been a problem in Git iself, `strncat()` found it's way into '`master`' of `cgit` and caused segfaults on my system.

---

With Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), it uses the explicit form of '`vsprintf`' as the banned version of itself, not '`sprintf`'.

See [commit 60d198d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/60d198d022656c543c554fce3c665114c5a69430) (25 Aug 2019) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 37801f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37801f0665623e354e91ddd9c0bd5a2a4530fa24), 30 Sep 2019)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41870235/2410359) that suggested `snprintf()`:  (Note: trouble if `n <= 0`)

```
size_t sz = sizeof buf;
/*n is the number of characters to be copied from source*/
int n = (int) sz - 1;
snprintf(buf, sz, "%s", src);
```

code can use the following *precision*:

> "... the maximum number of bytes to be written for `s` conversions. ..." C11 §7.21.6.1 4

```
sprintf(buf, "%.*s", n, src);
```

It has the subtle advantage in that `src` need not be a *string*, just an array of characters.

Another tool for strings.

Comment: @chqrlie Answer re-worked.  From OP's "*n is the number of characters to be copied from source". not the size of the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `strlcpy()` function.

`strlcpy()` takes the full size of the destination buffer and guarantee NULL-termination if there is room. Read [man](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strlcpy&sektion=3) page for more information.

Comment: I don't think `strlcpy` is standard and I for one would prefer standard functions here.

Comment: There's the `strcpy_s` function which is standard as per C11, but compilers need not support it. Still it is more standard than `strlcpy`. And there is no real reason to use either of them...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you mean `strncpy_s`. But `strncpy_s` is prone for off-by-one errors. Apparently, one has to specify the target buffer size minus one. `strlcpy` is much more natural.

Answer (score 1):

The `strcpy` function always null-terminates.  Of course you should include code to prevent buffer overflows, e.g.:

```
char buf[50];

if (strlen(src) >= sizeof buf)
{
    // do something else...
}
else
    strcpy(buf, src);
```

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted.  If you know the size of the buffer it's an obvious alternative.  If you don't know the size of the buffer you have no way to do a safe copy anyway.