# What are the contents of the memory just allocated by `malloc()`?

Tags: c, initialization, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was curious about what exactly a pointer holds, after `malloc()` was used to allocate memory space? The manpage tells me that `calloc()` initializes the allocated memory space with zero.

> The  malloc()  function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  **The memory is not initialized**.  If size is 0, then malloc() returns  either  NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free().

and

> The calloc() function allocates memory for an array of nmemb elements of size bytes each
>          and  returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  **The memory is set to zero**.  If nmemb or
>          size is 0, then calloc() returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that  can  later
>          be successfully passed to free().

I created a really short example program in C, to C(haha) for myself:

```
int main() {
    char *dynamic_chars;
    unsigned amount;
    printf("how much bytes you want to allocate?\n");
    scanf("%d", &amount);

    dynamic_chars = (char*)malloc(amount*sizeof(char));
    printf("allocated:\n%s\n", dynamic_chars);

    free(dynamic_chars);
    return 0;
```

}

However when executing this code, it just outputs nothing. If I initialize the memory my self for example initializing every single byte with `0xFFFF` using a loop, then the program shows me exactly what I expect. The memory space actually exists, since I wont get an error claiming that I am trying to access uninitialized variables or so.

Since memory space is usually not deleted but marked as rewritable I wonder if by executing my program, shouldn't I be able to see random previously used Bytes of memory? But I wont see anything, so I am really confused about how exactly `malloc()` works.

## EDIT1

Another thing about `malloc()` or maybe memory usage in general, that is interesting about my program:
If I use `calloc()`, to allocate memory, I can trace the actual memory usage of my program, by e.g. monitoring it. For example, if I tell my program, to allocate 1.000.000.000 Bytes of memory per `calloc()` I will see the following in my System monitor:
[image: Memory consumption when using <code>calloc()</code>]

As you can probably imagine, when using `malloc()`, I wont see nothing. I understand, that just by allocating memory, I am not really using it at that time, but I am still confused about why my operating system (unix derivate) won't recognize it as being used. Since `malloc()` just like `calloc()` returns a physical address to a memory location I don't get, how this memory area seems to be not actually reserved by the OS. Elsewise I could see it in the System Monitor right? 
If I should rather post this as a new question, please let me know. But I think since the question is still about how `malloc()` works it fits in here.

Comment: Tends to be 0 by accident when you test it like this.  That won't repeat well when you do it in a real program and previously freed heap blocks are getting recycled.  You are not allowed to make any assumptions.

Comment: If the memory begins with zero, `printf` takes it as `""` (zero being the terminaison caracter) You should use another method if you want to see the real values.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &amount);` → `scanf("%u", &amount);`

Comment: I think the answer to "edit 1" part of your question is probably implementation/os specific, but since calloc requires contiguous memory and malloc can use fragments, it is possible that malloc can use memory already allocated for your program while calloc needs to reserve "new" memory. Or malloc can postpone the actual reservation until the time the memory is actually used.

Comment: Note: Why use type `unsigned amount;`?  Review the paramter type accepted by `malloc()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, `malloc()` returns uninitialized memory, the contents of which is indeterminate. So, attempt to *use* the value invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, annex §J.2, *Undefined behavior*

> The value of the object allocated by the `malloc` function is used

In this case, `%s` expects a null-terminated `char` array. However, the content of `dynamic_chars` is indeterminate, so there may very well be no null-terminator, at all, which will cause the out-of-bound memory access, which in turn invokes the UB.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5, The `malloc` function (*emphasis mine*):

> The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by `size` and
>   **whose value is indeterminate.**

That said, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Not to be confused with [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) that initializes the allocated memory!

Comment: @gsamaras I thought the question is specific about `malloc()`, isn't it? :)

Comment: Sourav sure, but it was just some says before that a new-comer was confused with these two. Maybe I should delete my comments?

Comment: @gsamaras Not at all, It's helpful, nonetheless. Let both our comments be there. :)

Comment: OK, now, reason behind downvote, anybody? What did I miss?

Comment: Why would *reading* uninitialized memory lead to undefined behavior? You get an undefined result (as far as the specification is concerned), but surely the *behavior* is as it should be?

Comment: @RadLexus reading indeterminate values as `char` may produce a trap representation. But even on systems with no trap representations, passing an indeterminate value to a library function such as `printf` is not defined. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25074258/1505939) for further discussion

Comment: @RadLexus Just to add a bit more context, C11 specifically mentions this case as UB. Please note the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's undefined by the C language what the memory block contains when you get it. In practice it will most likely simply contain what was in that physical memory previously.

If the memory was previously used by your program and freed you'll likely just get what was in it before. If it's memory newly requested from the operating system you'll get what the operating system put in it. Most operating systems return memory that has been specifically set to 'zero' bytes because it would be a security issue if the memory still contained what was in it from some other program previously.

None of that is guaranteed by any standard, it's just what most systems do in practice.

Answer (score 2):

malloc allocates the memory for you and sets pointer to it. It does not initialize the memory in any way, so the allocated memory area can contain anything. Since it does not contain a string, you can't read it's content by printing a string. Instead you could print it byte by byte, like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<amount*sizeof(char);i++)
{
    printf("%02x", (unsigned)dynamic_chars[i]);
}
```

Comment: This passes indeterminate values to a library function. The C standard is unclear about this but [DR451 Proposed Committee Resolution](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_451.htm) recommends that this be undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M I don't understand why this code should be a problem. The values in `dynamic_chars` are certainly underterminate, but they are still just values and I don't see why it should be a problem to print the hexadecimal representation of these values.

Comment: @M.M good point on the %x, I made small improvement to fix it. However I have difficulty in understanding why would the behaviour of printf be undefined, the content definitely is (as mentioned by Michael Walz), but I don't understand why wouldn't it be possible to print out the content of the memory.

Comment: uninitialized memory doesn't have any contents, in Standard C. It sounds like you're imagining that it contains some value

Comment: @M.M ok I agree with you from the spec point of view. However, in practice for uninitialized memory not to contain any value, it would need to be unexisting memory before it is initialized. Have you even seen an implementation like that? I have not and I can not even imagine one.

Comment: In any case it should be safe to say that reading uninitialized memory like that is ok for study or debugging purposes, but may be unsafe for production.