# Uninitialized _Bool variable or struct field behaves strangely

Tags: c, boolean

The code below:

```
_Bool field0;
char field1;

printf("fieldX:                [%d]\t[%d]\n", field0,         field1);
printf("fieldX ? 1 : 0:        [%d]\t[%d]\n", field0 ? 1 : 0, field1 ? 1 : 0);
printf("!fieldX:               [%d]\t[%d]\n", !field0,        !field1);
printf("!!fieldX:              [%d]\t[%d]\n", !!field0,       !!field1);
```

Gives the following output:

> ```
> fieldX:                [165]  [165]
> fieldX ? 1 : 0:        [165]  [1]
> !fieldX:               [164]  [0]
> !!fieldX:              [165]  [1]
> ```

Looks quite surprising, especially ternary operator result.

Checked with gcc 4.9.3 and 4.8.3, -O0, no -flto.

Remark: the stack was previously initialized with 0xa5 pattern (embedded C environment).

Comment: Accessing an object with automatic storage invokes undefined behavior. Nothing strange here.

Comment: @ouah - do you miss a `uninitialized` in that comment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does "Undefined Behavior" really permit \*anything\* to happen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132574/does-undefined-behavior-really-permit-anything-to-happen)

Comment: Perhaps the compiler knows that an initialized `_Bool` can only have value `0` or `1`, so it optimizes `field0 ? 1 : 0` to `field0`

Comment: @4386427 thanks for noticing. Unfortunately, I'm no longer allowed to edit and add the missing word.

Comment: @M.M yes, totally makes sense.

The code above is actually a simplified one, the real code tried to check that multiple struct _Bool fields were properly mutually exclusively initialized (namely, in [Protobuf Union structure](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#union)). Actually, from now on, I'd like to avoid using _Bool whenever possible. Maybe that's not very professional -- but if I have used to use chars, ints etc that acted certain similar way, what for should I increase the possibility to shoot myself in my leg, right?

Comment: @OlegTcaregorodtcev to avoid problems, don't use uninitialized variables. You should not rely on behaviour of uninitialized `char` or anything else either.  It is not possible to test if something is uninitialized, it's the responsibility of the calling code to not declare uninitialized variables and pass them around.

Comment: @M.M totally agree with you, in fact, gcc will emit a compile-time warning upon an uninitialized local variable (-Wall -Wextra). But I was unable to find how to make it emitting the same warning for uninitialized struct field. I was writing a function that would be like EncodeAndSendProtobuf(PB_Struct *s). And it'd be great to implement something like checking contracts (I hope I got the concept right). I see nothing wrong with "fail fast" principle. So I'm not relying on the undefined behaviour here to convey some "production-grade" data, but rather to use it to conduct additional checks.

Comment: Some people recommend always initializing every variable declaration. (the compiler will optimize it out if the value is always overwritten before first use)

Comment: That's a good strategy to employ. But the reality is that I myself almost always work in teams, and we are all people, so... I'd like to write modules/functions in a way so that they treat their input as unreliable. The more checks -- the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing an uninitialized object with automatic storage invokes undefined behavior. So nothing strange here.

Moreover a `_Bool` object can only hold two values: either `0` or `1`. An implementation is allowed to replace `!!boolean_object` or `boolean_object ? 1 : 0` by `boolean_object`.

(Also note that even with `-O0`, `gcc` is still performing some optimizations: for example, it inlines static functions called once.)

Answer (score 1):

Accessing an uninitialized automatic variable causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) in most cases, in this one.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074180/is-aa-or-a-a-undefined-behaviour-if-a-is-not-initialized/25074276) for the exact details of "most".