# How to safely implement "Using Uninitialized Memory For Fun And Profit"?

Tags: c++, data-structures, valgrind

I would like to build a dense integer set in C++ using the trick described at https://research.swtch.com/sparse .  This approach achieves good performance by allowing itself to read uninitialized memory.

How can I implement this data structure without triggering undefined behavior, and without running afoul of tools like Valgrand or ASAN?

Edit: It seems like responders are focusing on the word "uninitialized" and interpreting it in the context of the language standard. That was probably a poor word choice on my part - here "uninitialized" means only that its value is not important to the correct functioning of the algorithm. It's obviously possible to implement this data structure safely (LLVM does it in SparseMultiSet). My question is what is the best and most performant way to do so?

Comment: Reading uninitialized memory is undefined behavior. You can't even assume that reading values from an uninitialized array of `int` yields an `int`. For example, the compiler may optimize out any branch guaranteed to contain undefined behavior.

Comment: Reading an indeterminate value is not undefined in some cases, in particular for unsigned char. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415661/has-c-standard-changed-with-respect-to-the-use-of-indeterminate-values-and-und

Comment: Using that indeterminate value for indexing the other array is UB.  Comparing it to anything is UB.  The only operation allowed is making a copy, and the copy is then also indeterminate.

Comment: Perhaps writing it in C is an option?  It looks like C provides more guarantees here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c

Comment: @ridiculous_fish - although that answer seems to give hope for `C`, it doesn't seem like its conclusion is correct, at least for C11 and later. See for example the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25074180/149138). The takeaway seems to be that, yes, you can have indeterminate or unspecified values not causing _UB_ when used in an expression (e.g., a comparison), but that the result is always indeterminate. In particular, the second evaluation of `sparse[i]` in the `is-member` check may apparently return a different value than the first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see four basic approaches you can take. These are applicable not only to C++ but also most other low-level languages like C that make uninitialized access possible but not *allowed*, and the last is applicable even to higher-level "safe" languages.

## Ignore the standard, implement it in the usual way

This is the one crazy trick language lawyers hate! Don't freak out yet though - the solutions following this one won't break the rules, so just skip this part if you are of the rules-stickler variety.

The standard makes most uses of uninitialized values *undefined* and the few loopholes it does allow (e.g., copying one undefined value to another) don't really give you enough rope to actually implement what you want - even in C which is slightly less restrictive (see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25074258/149138) covering C11, which explains that while accessing an `indeterminiate` value may not directly trigger *UB* anything that results is also *indeterminate* and indeed the value may appear to chance from access to access).

So you just implement it anyway, with the knowledge that most or all currently compilers will just compile it to the expected code, and know that your code is not standards compliant.

At least in [my test](https://godbolt.org/g/CSIUQ5) all of `gcc`, `clang` and `icc` didn't take advantage of the illegal access to do anything crazy. Of course, the test is not comprehensive and even if you could construct one, the behavior could change in a new version of the compiler.

You would be safest if the implementation of the methods that access uninitialized memory was compiled, once, in a separate compilation unit - this makes it easy to check that it does the right thing (just check the assembly once) and makes it nearly impossible (outside of LTGC) for the compiler to do anything tricky, since it can't prove whether uninitialized values are being accessed.

Still, this approach is theoretically *unsafe* and you should check the compiled output very carefully and have additional safeguards in place if you take it.

If you take this approach, tools like `valgrind` are fairly likely to report a uninitialized read error.

Now these tools work at the assembly level, and some uninitialized reads may be fine (see, for example, the next item on fast standard library implementations), so they don't actually report a uninitialized read immediately, but rather have a variety of heuristics to determine if invalid values are *actually used*. For example, they may avoid reporting an error until they determine the uninitialized value is used to determine the direction of a conditional jump, or some other action that is not trackable/recoverable according to the heuristic. You *may* be able to get the compiler to emit code that reads uninitialized memory but is safe according to this heuristic.

More likely, you won't be able to do that (since the logic here is fairly subtle as it relies on the relationship between the values in two arrays), so you can use the *suppression* options in your tools of choice to hide the errors. For example, valgrind can suppress based on the [stack trace](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) - and in fact there are already many such suppression entries used by default to hide false-positives in various standard libraries.

Since it works based on stack traces, you'll probably have difficulties if the reads occur in inlined code, since the top-of-stack will then be different for every call-site. You could avoid this my making sure the function is not inlined.

## Use assembly

What is ill-defined in the standard, is usually well-defined at the assembly level. It is why the compiler and standard library can often implement things in a faster way than you could achieve with C or C++: a `libc` routine written in assembly is already targeting a specific architecture and doesn't have to worry about the various caveats in the language specification that are there to make things run fast on a variety of hardware.

Normally, implementing any serious amount of code in assembly is a costly undertaking, but here it is only a handful, so it may be feasible depending on how many platforms you are targeting. You don't even really need to write the methods yourself - just compile the C++ version (or use [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) and copy the assembly. The `is_member` function, for example<sup>1</sup>, looks like:

```
sparse_array::is_member(unsigned long):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+16]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax+rsi*8]
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        jnb     .L1
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rax+rdx*8], rsi
        sete    al
```

## Rely on `calloc` magic

If you use [`calloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/)<sup>2</sup>, you explicitly request zeroed memory from the underlying allocator. Now a *correct* version of `calloc` may simply call `malloc` and then zero out the returned memory, but actual implementations rely on the fact that the OS-level memory allocation routines (`sbrk` and `mmap`, pretty much) will generally return you zeroed memory on any OS with protected memory (i.e., all the big ones), to avoid zeroing out the memory again.

As a practical matter, for large allocations, this is typically satisfied by implementing a call like anonymous `mmap` by mapping a special *zero page* of all zeros. When (if ever) the memory is written, does copy-on-write actually allocate a new page. So the allocation of large, zeroed memory regions may be *for free* since the OS already needs to zero the pages.

In that case, implementing your sparse set on top of `calloc` could be just as fast as the nominally uninitialized version, while being safe and standards compliant.

#### Calloc Caveats

You should of course test to ensure that `calloc` is behaving as expected. The optimized behavior is usually only going to occur when your program initializes a lot of long-lived zeroed memory approximately "up-front". That is, the typical logic for optimized calloc if something like this:

```
calloc(N)
  if (can satisfy a request for N bytes from allocated-then-freed memory)
    memset those bytes to zero and return them
  else
    ask the OS for memory, return it directly because it is zeroed
```

Basically, the `malloc` infrastructure (which also underlies `new` and friends) has a (possibly empty) pool of memory that it has already requested from the OS and generally tries to allocated there first. This pool is composed of memory from the last block request from the OS but not handed out (e.g., because the user requested 32 bytes but the allocated asks for chunks from the OS in 1 MB blocks, so there is a lot left over), and also of memory that was handed out to the process but subsequently returned via `free` or `delete` or whatever. The memory in that pool has arbitrary values, and if a `calloc` can be satisfied from that pool, you don't get your magic, since the zero-init has to occur.

On the other hand if the memory has to be allocated from the OS, you get the magic. So it depends on your use case: if you are frequently creating and destroying `sparse_set` objects, you will generally just be drawing from the internal `malloc` pools and will pay the zeroing costs. If you have a long-lived `sparse_set` objects which take up a lot of memory, they likely were allocated by asking the OS and you got the zeroing nearly for free.

The good news is that if you don't want to rely on the `calloc` behavior above (indeed, on your OS or with your allocator it may not even be optimized in that way), you could usually replicate the behavior by mapping in `/dev/zero` manually for your allocations. On OSes that offer it, this guarantees that you get the "cheap" behavior.

## Use Lazy Initialization

For a solution that is totally platform agnostic you could simply use yet another array which tracks the initialization state of the array.

First you choose some granule, at which you will track initialization, and use bitmap where each bit tracks the initialization state of that granule of the `sparse` array.

For example, let's say you choose your granule to be 4 elements, and the size of the elements in your array is 4 bytes (e.g., `int32_t` values): you need 1 bit to track every 4 elements * 4 bytes/element * 8 bits/byte, which is an overhead of less than 1%<sup>3</sup> in allocated memory.

Now you simply check the corresponding bit in this array before accessing `sparse`. This adds some small cost to accessing the `sparse` array, but doesn't change the overall complexity, and the check is still quite fast.

For example, your `is_member` function now [looks like](https://godbolt.org/g/kp9zoT):

```
bool sparse_set::is_member(size_t i){
    bool init = is_init[i >> INIT_SHIFT] & (1UL << (i & INIT_MASK));
    return init && sparse[i] < n && dense[sparse[i]] == i;
}
```

The generated assembly on x86 (gcc) now starts with:

```
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+24]
mov     rdx, rsi
shr     rdx, 8
mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax+rdx*8]
xor     eax, eax
bt      rdx, rsi
jnc     .L2
...
```

.L2:
    ret

That's all associate with the bitmap check. It's all going to be pretty quick (and often off the critical path since it isn't part of the data flow).

In general, the cost of this approach depends on the density of your set, and what functions you are calling - `is_member` is about the worse case for this approach since some functions (e.g., `clear`) aren't affected at all, and others (e.g., `iterate`) can batch up the `is_init` check and only do it once every `INIT_COVERAGE` elements (meaning the overhead would be again ~1% for the example values).

Sometimes this approach will be *faster* than the approach suggested in the OP's link, especially when the handling elements not in the set - in this case, the `is_init` check will fail and often shortcut the remaining code, and in this case you have a working set that is much smaller (256 times using the example granule size) than the size of the `sparse` array, so you may great reduce misses to DRAM or outer cache levels.

The granule size itself is an important tunable for this approach. Intuitively, a larger granule size pays a larger initialization cost when the an element covered by the granule is accessed for the first time, but saves on memory and up-front `is_init` initialization cost. You can come up with a formula that finds the optimum size in the simple case - but the behavior also depends on the "clustering" of values and other factors. Finally, it is totally reasonable to use a dynamic granule size to cover your bases under varying workloads - but it comes at the cost of variable shifts.

#### Really Lazy Solution

It is worth noting that there is a similarity between the `calloc` and *lazy init* solutions: both lazily initialize blocks of memory as they are needed, but the `calloc` solution track this implicitly in hardware through MMU magic with page tables and TLB entries, while the *lazy init* solution does it in software, with a bitmap explicitly tracking which granules have been allocated.

The hardware approach has the advantage of being nearly free in (for the "hit" case, anyway) since it uses the always-present virtual memory support in the CPU to detect misses, but the software case has the advantage of being portable and allowing precise control over the granule size etc.

You can actually combine these approaches, to make a lazy approach that doesn't use a bitmap, and doesn't even need the `dense` array at all: just allocate your `sparse` array with `mmap` as `PROT_NONE`, so you fault whenever you read from an un-allocated page in a `sparse` array. You catch the fault and allocate the page in the `sparse` array with a sentinel value indicating "not present" for every element.

This is the fastest of all for the "hot" case: you don't need any of the `... && dense[sparse[i]] == i` checks any more.

The downsides are:

- Your code is really not portable since you need to implement the fault-handling logic, which is usually platform specific.
- You can't control the granule size: it must be at page granularity (or some multiple thereof). If your set is very sparse (say less than 1 out of 4096 elements occupied) and uniformly distributed, you end up paying a high initialization cost since you need to handle a fault and initialize a full page of values for every element.
- Misses (i.e., non-insert accesses to set elements that don't exist) either need to allocate a page even if no elements will exist in that range, or will be very slow (incurring a fault) every time.

---

<sup>1</sup> This implementation has no "range checking" - i.e., it doesn't check if `i` is greater than `MAX_ELEM` - depending on your use case you may want to check this. My implementation used a template parameter for `MAX_ELEM`, which may result in slightly faster code, but also more bloat, and you'd do fine to just make the max size a class member as well.

<sup>2</sup> Really, the only requirement that you use something that calls `calloc` under the covers or performs the equivalent zero-fill optimization, but based on my tests more idiomatic C++ approaches like `new int[size]()` just do the allocation followed by a `memset`. `gcc` *does* optimize `malloc` followed by `memset` into `calloc`, but that's not useful if you are trying to avoid the use of C routines anyway!

<sup>3</sup> Precisely, you need 1 extra bit to track every 128 bits of the `sparse` array.

Comment: Also, statically-allocated fixed-size arrays get initialized to zeroes at program startup, usually without runtime cost.

Comment: @Davislor - yeah, although the cost is basically equivalent to a `calloc` with the difference that it always uses the OS-level zero-path, since there isn't any other pool of OS-allocated memory to draw from. It's also usually handled by the runtime linker so it could in principle use a different path (for better or worse) than the runtime memory allocation stuff. Statically initialized arrays are of limited use for a general purpose data structure, however, since you'd need to know at compile-time how big you'd want it, etc.

Comment: Note that since Valgrind 3.10, suppression logic takes inlining into account, as long as the compiler generates Dwarf inlining debug info.

Answer (score 2):

If we reword your question:

> What code reads from uninitialized memory without tripping tools designed to catch reads from uninitialized memory?

Then the answer becomes clear -- it is not possible.  Any way of doing this that you could find represents a bug in Valgrind that would be fixed.

Maybe it's possible to get the same performance without UB, but the restrictions you put on your question "I would like to... use the trick... allowing itself to read uninitialized memory" guarantee UB.  Any competing method avoiding UB will not be using the trick that you so love.

Comment: Valgrind enables selectively suppressing errors, does it not? Also I don't understand why UB is guaranteed in this case.

Comment: @ridiculouz_fish à condition that depends on initialized data is in itself UB. It may happen that you read a number and that number doesn't even exist in memory. Reading uninitialized data is just undefined behavior. End of the story.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind does not complain if you just read uninitialised memory.
Valgrind will complain if you *use* this data in a way that influences
the visible behaviour of the program, e.g. using this data as input in a syscall, or doing a jump based on this data, or using this data to commpute another address. See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.uninitvals for more info.
So, it might very well be that you will have no problem with Valgrind.

If valgrind still complain but your algorithm is correct even when using this uninit data, then you can use client requests to declare this memory as initialised.

Comment: Yes, but of course this is just a heuristic. Valgrind has a variety of heuristics that try to distinguish between a "harmless read" of un-init memory, and a "real bug", but they are generally conservative (i.e., they try to eliminate some false-positives, but not incur any false-negatives). They aren't perfect: there are many cases where the behavior is too complex to determine accurately whether a use of uninit is harmful or not.