# Is it UB to use zero multiplied uninitialized variable?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

Is there UB in the following code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    printf("%d", 0*x);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the variable `x` was not initialized, but was multiplied by `0` and the result was passed to `printf`. Mathematically, the result passed to `printf` should be `0`, but I guess that in c language this invokes UB. If the variable was not multiplied by `0` it is clearly UB but I am not sure is it UB in this particular case.

[Ideone link](https://ideone.com/aUT5WV)

Comment: UB is not "something bad happens". UB is "compiler is allowed to do anything it wants". Using uninitialized value is a permission to compiler to do anything - including returning 0.

Comment: You'll probably hit UB _before_ multiplication.

Comment: @SouravGhosh this should be a better duplicate [Is a^a or a-a undefined behaviour if a is not initialized?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25074180/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Sure, just added that. :)

Comment: ...and someone would do this because......?

Comment: Better duplicate still: [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's UB.

A conforming compiler may not do any optimization and run into a trap representation in `x`.
Some implementations may reserve some bits for special values, including trap representations.

Comment: I do not think that it is UB. - simply `x` can be given any junk value and `0*x` will be 0.

Comment: Why downvotes for this answer ?

Comment: @EdHeal: some implementations may reserve some bits of `int` for trap values.

Comment: @EdHeal, not just trap representations, some compilers might also run into bad optimizations because of the UB.

Comment: What are the trap representations for an `int`?

Comment: Usual hardware (Intel, AMD, ...) does not have the concept of trap representation. But imagine a 9-bit computer where it finds a value with all 9 bits set to 1 causes it to reboot.

Comment: ...although traps representations for integer values are highly unlikely today.

Comment: If `int` does not have a trap value, will the behaviour be undefined?

Comment: It is not UB because of trap representations, but because the variable has automatic storage and never has its address taken. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40674888/584518). Trap representations are mostly irrelevant in real-world computers. If this variable had its address taken and the system did not support trap represenation, it would have been merely unspecified behavior.

Comment: Would it be unspecified behavour in the latter case?

Comment: @Lundin: On gcc 5.4.1 for the ARM, using `memcpy` to copy a partially-written struct containing two `uint16_t` values may yield a copy with a field containing a value outside the range 0-65535.  Using `memcpy` on a partially-written structure should be defined behavior, but gcc sometimes optimizes away the `memcpy`, even though it would render otherwise-undefined behavior, defined.

Comment: @supercat What does that have to do with trap representations? The ARM ABI does not have trap representations. It rather sounds like something related to pointer aliasing, which has nothing to do with this topic.

Comment: @Lundin: You say that a defining factor is that an object's address is not taken.  Applying `memcpy` to an object implies taking its address, thus forbidding a compiler from regarding it as an "object of automatic duration whose address has not been taken".  The only other way that reading object of an unsigned integer type could behave as though it yielded an object outside its range would be if it could hold a trap representation.

Comment: @supercat memcpy does indeed mean that the address is taken. The UB related to automatic storage duration variables means that they might be allocated in CPU registers unless you take their address. If the address is taken, then that part isn't relevant and you end up with an indeterminate value, which could either be an unspecified value (in 99.99% of all real-world computers) or a trap representation (in wildly exotic, barely existing computers). Again, the issue you describe seems related to pointer aliasing and not to indeterminate values.

Comment: @Lundin: My point is that some optimizers will replace code that takes an object's address with code that doesn't, and then treat the object as though the address isn't taken.

Comment: Am I right that UB is invoked exactly in this piece of code: `0*x` ? And not somewhere inside `printf` when the value is about to be printed ?

Comment: @supercat The standard is clear, so if a compiler does something else, then it is not conforming.

Comment: @ks1322 Yes you invoke UB as soon as `x` is accessed. It is a local variable and its address had not been taken, so it is UB as per 6.3.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behavior, as this may cause a trap representation.

From the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

Uniitialized variables, section 6.7.9:

> *10* If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is **indeterminate**.

The definition of indeterminate, Section 3.19.2:

> **indeterminate value**
>
> either an unspecified value or a **trap representation**

The definition of trap representation, Section 3.19.4:

> **trap representation**
>
> an object representation that need not represent a value of the object
>   type

Comment: What are the trap representations for an int?

Comment: No this is not (necessarily) why this is UB. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c/40674888#40674888). In real-world computers there exist no trap representations so any discussion about them is irrelevant to the real world.