# C++ How to make std::function<bool()> to return a boolean value

Tags: c++

I have the following small code example:

```
std::function<bool()> isSet;

bool check() {
   bool tmp;
   return tmp;
}

std::function<bool()> isSet {
    return check();
}
```

This gives me the following error message

```
could not convert 'isSet()' from 'bool' to 'std::function<bool()>'
```

Can anyone explain why and how I to fix it?

Comment: return check; ?

Comment: Your `check` function returns an uninitialized value. It isn't clear what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you initialize a `std::function` you just give it the function you want it to use.  That would look like

```
bool check() {
   bool tmp;
   return tmp;
}

std::function<bool()> isSet { check };
```

What you almost did was make a lambda, which you could do, but the syntax would be

```
std::function<bool()> isSet { [](){ return check(); } };
```

---

Do note that `check` returns an uninitialized variable which is undefined behavior: [Why is returning a non-initialized value considered undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980679/why-is-returning-a-non-initialized-value-considered-undefined-behavior)

Comment: Thanks,, yes,, it was a 'typo' in check to return a uninitialized. I just so sorry that there are people hanging around on stackoverflow more interested in finding errors than helping.....   YOU helped alot..... Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`std::function<bool()> isSet` is a regular old object, not a function. You are supposed to initialize it with a functor it can hold, not provide function block to execute.

Simply fix the initialization

```
std::function<bool()> isSet { check }; // Hold a pointer to check
```