# Is reading an uninitialized value always an undefined behaviour? Or are there exceptions to it?

Tags: c, initialization, undefined-behavior

An obvious example of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB), when reading a value, is:

```
int a;
printf("%d\n", a);
```

What about the following examples?

```
int i = i;     // `i` is not initialized when we are reading it by assigning it to itself.
int x; x = x;  // Is this the same as above?
int y; int z = y;
```

Are all three examples above also UB, or are there exceptions to it?

Comment: All three have *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: some folks here are saying first example is not UB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67662266/

Comment: Learning about [*trap representations*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725809/trap-representation/6725981#6725981) would be helpful.

Comment: @Dan the links from the duplicate you linked in comment, say that it is syntactically legal, but the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: They are saying using `i` later on will be undefined. I'm arguing `int i=i;` itself is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I think the ground has been fairly well covered already. You are asking the same question that was recently closed as a duplicate.

Comment: but never got to a concussion. is it UB or not? all 3 above are?

Comment: Reading from an uninitialised variable is undefined behaviour. Right there and then.

Comment: ye but some are saying `int i = i; ` isn't actually reading `i`, hence NOT UB. please check the comments on the link.

Comment: If you think that `int i = i;` isn't doing anything, why is it in your code?

Comment: `int i = i;` is semantically equivalent to `int i; i = i;` Both are UB. But just because you have UB in your code doesn't mean the compiler have to do something about it, it's part of the whole undefined bit. A decent compiler will be able to detect it and warn you about it though, but from the compilers point of view it's not an error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude LOL he has other question, and I have been corrected few times before, but `int i; i = i` invokes UBs, but is `int i = i` in itself is not UB, per say?

Comment: @KPCT they are all UB.

Comment: It is not because of what the compiler, or the processor might or might not do, but *because the C standard says so* although I can't find the relevant clause.

Comment: @Dan is it OK if I tweak your question?

Comment: Just saying, the rules might be slightly different in C vs C++. The links I posted under your previous question were for C++.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat welcome to this DUPE. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have a question for you. Look at this other way int a; ... might cause UB, but `int a; a = 5` is not UB. thus `int a = a` it depends on next line. So `int a = a; a = 5` is this UB, I do not think so?

Comment: For more in-depth analysis see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074180/  . (I would suggest this is a duplicate; even though the question is not exactly the same, the same answers do apply)

Comment: It's UB. For example in Itanium [reading an uninitialized variable triggers a trap](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150727-00/?p=90821). See [Is a^a or a-a undefined behaviour if a is not initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25074180/995714)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each of the three lines triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  The key part of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), that explains this, is section 6.3.2.1p2 regarding *Conversions*:

> Except  when  it  is  the  operand  of  the `sizeof` operator,  the
> `_Alignof` operator,  the unary `&` operator, the `++` operator, the
> `--` operator, or the left operand of the `.` operator or  an
> assignment  operator,  an  lvalue  that  does  not  have  array  type
> is  converted  to  the value  stored  in  the  designated  object
> (and  is  no  longer  an  lvalue);  this  is  called *lvalue
> conversion*. If the  lvalue  has  qualified  type,  the  value  has
> the  unqualified  version  of  the type of the lvalue; additionally,
> if the lvalue has atomic type, the value has the non-atomic version
> of  the  type  of  the  lvalue;  otherwise,  the  value  has  the
> type  of  the  lvalue.   If the lvalue has an incomplete type and does
> not have array type, the behavior is undefined.  **If the  lvalue
> designates  an  object  of  automatic  storage  duration  that  could
> have  been declared with the `register` storage class (never had its
> address taken), and that object is  uninitialized  (not  declared
> with  an  initializer  and  no  assignment  to  it  has  been
> performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.**

In each of the three cases, an uninitialized variable is used as the right-hand side of an assignment or initialization (which for this purpose is equivalent to an assignment) and undergoes lvalue to rvalue conversion.  The part in bold applies here as the objects in question have not been initialized.

This also applies to the `int i = i;` case as the lvalue on the right side has not (yet) been initialized.

There was debate in a related question that the right side of `int i = i;` is UB because the lifetime of `i` has not yet begun. However, that is not the case.  From section 6.2.4 p5 and p6:

> *5* An  object  whose  identifier  is  declared  with  no  linkage  and  without  the  storage-class specifier `static` has *automatic
> storage  duration*, as do some  compound  literals.  The result of
> attempting to indirectly access an object with automatic storage
> duration from a thread other than the one with which the object is
> associated is implementation-defined.
>
> *6* **For  such  an  object  that  does  not  have  a  variable  length  array  type,  its  lifetime  extends from entry into the block
> with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any
> way.**  (Entering  an  enclosed  block  or  calling  a  function
> suspends,  but  does  not  end,execution of the current block.)  If
> the block is entered recursively, a new instance of the object  is
> created  each  time.   The  initial  value  of  the  object  is
> indeterminate.   If  an initialization  is  specified  for  the
> object,  it  is  performed  each  time  the  declaration  or compound
> literal  is  reached  in  the  execution  of  the  block;  otherwise,
> the  value  becomes indeterminate each time the declaration is reached

So in this case the lifetime of `i` begins *before* the declaration in encountered.  So `int i = i;` is still undefined behavior, but not for this reason.

The bolded part of 6.3.2.1p2 does however open the door for use of an uninitialized variable *not* being undefined behavior, and that is if the variable in question had it's address taken.  For example:

```
int a;
printf("%p\n", (void *)&a);
printf("%d\n", a);
```

In this case it is not undefined behavior *if*:

- The implementation does not have trap representations for the given type, OR
- The value chosen for `a` happens to not be a trap representation.

In which case the value of `a` is **unspecified**.  In particular, this will be the case with [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) and [Microsoft Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) (MSVC) in this example as these implementations do not have trap representations for integer types.

Comment: Look at this other way `int a; ...` might cause UB, but `int a; a = 5` is not UB. thus `int a = a` it depends on next line. So `int a = a; a = 5` is this UB, I think not?

Comment: @KPCT The second line doesn't matter.  `int a = a;` by itself is undefined behavior as per 6.3.2.1p1.  If at some point later `&a` was used then it might not be UB depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Use of the not initialized automatic storage duration objects invokes UB.

Use of the not initialized static storage duration objects is defined as they are initialized to 0s

```
int a;

int foo(void)
{
    static int b;
    int c;
    
    int d = d;           //UB
    static int e = e;    //OK

    printf("%d\n", a);   //OK
    printf("%d\n", b);   //OK
    printf("%d\n", c);   //UB

}
```

Comment: `is UB or not when..` was this an answer or a question?

Comment: Assume compiler optimization is disabled, then is it UB on its own?

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. It could still provide assembly but be UB in general. maybe it woks in one compiler but not in another.

Comment: @Dan yes clang generates the code. It is UB

Answer (score 1):

In cases where an action on an object of some type might have unpredictable consequences on platforms where the type has trap representations, but have at-least-somewhat predictable behavior for types that don't, the Standard will seek to avoid distinguishing platforms that do or don't define the behavior by throwing everything into the catch-all category of "Undefined Behavior".

With regard to the behavior of uninitialized or partially-initialized objects, I don't think there's ever been a consensus over exactly which corner cases must be treated as though objects were initialized with Unspecified bit patterns, and which cases need not be treated in such fashion.

For example, given something like:

```
struct ztstr15 { char dat[16]; } x,y;
void test(void)
{
  struct zstr15 hey;
  strcpy(hey.dat, "Hey");
  x=hey;
  y=hey;
}
```

Depending upon how `x` and `y` will be used, there are at least four ways it might be useful to have an implementation process the above code:

1. Squawk if an attempt is made to copy any automatic-duration object that isn't fully initialized.  This could be very useful in cases where one must avoid leakage of confidential information.
2. Zero-fill all unused portions of `hey`.  This would prevent leakage of confidential information on the stack, but wouldn't flag code that might cause such leakage if the data weren't zero-filled.
3. Ensure that all parts of `x` and `y` are identical, without regard for whether the corresponding members of `hey` were written.
4. Write the first four bytes of `x` and `y` to match those of `hey`, but leave some or all of the remaining portions holding whatever they held before `test()` was called.

I don't think the Standard was intended to pass judgment as to whether some of those approaches would be better or worse than others, but it would have been awkward to write the Standard in a manner that would define behavior of `test()` while allowing for option #3.  The optimizations facilitated by #3 would only be useful if programmers could safely write code like the above in cases where client code wouldn't care about the contents of `x.dat[4..15]` and `y.dat[4..15]`.  If the only way to guarantee anything about the behavior of that function would be to write all portions of `hey` were written, including those whose values would be irrelevant to program behavior, that would nullify any optimization advantage approach #3 could have offered.